# Loop is not stopping

Tags: python, while-loop

I was trying to make a loop decorator, i tried and it works, and for it to actually start i need to set a variable called start into True, however after it start, however i can't call the stop function, or even other function below where the start function code is

```
from time import time
from asyncio import sleep


class Looper:
    def __init__(self, fn, seconds, args, kwargs):
        self.fn = fn
        self.interval_ms = seconds / 1000
        self.time_last = time()
        self.started = False
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs

    def loop(self):
        time_now = time()
        if time_now >= self.time_last + self.interval_ms:
            self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
            self.time_last = time_now
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def set_interval_ms(self, interval_ms):
        self.interval_ms = interval_ms / 1000

    def set_interval_s(self, set_interval):
        self.interval_ms = set_interval

    def get_interval_ms(self):
        return self.interval_ms

    def get_interval_s(self):
        return self.interval_ms * 1000

    def start(self):
        self.started = True
        while True:
            if self.started:
                self.loop()
            else:
                break

    def stop(self):
        self.started = False


def loop(seconds):
    def inner(func):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            return Looper(func, seconds * 1000, args, kwargs)
        return wrapper
    return inner


@loop(seconds=1)
def test_function(args1):
    print(args1)


test_loop = test_function(args1="hi")
test_loop.start()
sleep(5)
print("HELLO") # This thing is not even executed i guess?
test_loop.stop()
```

Comment: in start function you set started to true and then go in infinite while loop. when are you setting started to false to exit the infinite while loop?

Comment: @AlbinPaul I'm trying to stop it when the stop function called and set the started value to False

Comment: You only test for `self.started`, not for the result of `self.loop()` to break out of your while loop. Since `self.started` is never altered, the loop continues endlessly.

Comment: You could probably just use `while self.loop(): pass` in `def start(self)`; nothing else needed.

Answer (score 0):

Your `start` function is blocking execution, it won't release control by itself, so there's no chance to reach the point where you set the `started` flag to `False` in order to break the loop.

From my perspective, you want two independent things to happen: A) execute a loop and B) control the start / stop of a loop. You'll need some concurrency mechanism to execute both. For example, you could put your `loop` in a separate thread.

Other things I've noticed:

- you're not doing anything with the return value of the `loop` function. Is that intended?
- your mechanism for "waiting" a particular interval will place excessive load on the CPU, I would add a sleep in there to let other task execute.